# Using Eventbrite API to login to an app

Tags: api, authentication, eventbrite

I'm looking to use a persons Eventbrite login details to login to an event based application.

This would be my first time doing this sort of feature so I was wondering if it is at all possible?

The [API documentation](http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/user-details/) provides details on getting a users details, given their name but I would like to authenticate the user by providing an Eventbrite username and password.

Would this be possible? Also what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a person's Eventbrite login information to login to an apllication outside of Eventbrite.

You could, on the other hand, have the user go through the [OAuth Token Flow](http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/reference/authentication/#ebapi-oauth-token-flow) in order to allow you access to their account.